# Kontakt.io iBeacon gets scanned with too much interval on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I bought 3 kontakt.io iBeacon and I had no problem to create the code in order to scan them on IOS but for android I'm having some problems..
The error is that I can correctly scan the iBeacons once but after that they doesn't gets scanned anymore or they gets scanned after a long period of time, this is the code I've used so far:

```
public class BeaconMonitorActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1;

    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.newInstance(this);
        beaconManager.setMonitorPeriod(MonitorPeriod.MINIMAL);
        beaconManager.setScanMode(1);
        beaconManager.setForceScanConfiguration(ForceScanConfiguration.DEFAULT);
        beaconManager.registerMonitoringListener(new BeaconManager.MonitoringListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMonitorStart() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMonitorStop() {}

            @Override
            public void onBeaconsUpdated(final Region region, final List<BeaconDevice> beacons) {}

            @Override
            public void onBeaconAppeared(final Region region, final BeaconDevice beacon) {

                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(
                    new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            if(beacon.getProximity() == Proximity.IMMEDIATE)
                            {
                                if(beacon.getMinor() == 33506)
                                {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BeaconMonitorActivity.this);
                                    builder.setMessage("Trovato iBeacon 1")
                                       .setCancelable(false)
                                       .setPositiveButton("Dettagli", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                BeaconMonitorActivity.this.finish();
                                           }
                                       })
                                       .setNegativeButton("Continua lo Scan", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                               try {
                                                beaconManager.startMonitoring();
                                            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                               try {
                                                    beaconManager.startMonitoring();
                                                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                           }
                                       });
                                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                                    alert.show();
                                }

                                if(beacon.getMinor() == 16706)
                                {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BeaconMonitorActivity.this);
                                    builder.setMessage("Trovato iBeacon 2")
                                       .setCancelable(false)
                                       .setPositiveButton("Dettagli", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                BeaconMonitorActivity.this.finish();
                                           }
                                       })
                                       .setNegativeButton("Continua lo Scan", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                               try {
                                                beaconManager.startMonitoring();
                                            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                               try {
                                                    beaconManager.startMonitoring();
                                                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                           }
                                       });
                                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                                    alert.show();
                                }

                                if(beacon.getMinor() == 48997)
                                {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BeaconMonitorActivity.this);
                                    builder.setMessage("Trovato iBeacon 3")
                                       .setCancelable(false)
                                       .setPositiveButton("Dettagli", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                BeaconMonitorActivity.this.finish();
                                           }
                                       })
                                       .setNegativeButton("Continua lo Scan", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                               try {
                                                beaconManager.startMonitoring();
                                            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                               try {
                                                beaconManager.startMonitoring();
                                            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                           }
                                       });
                                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                                    alert.show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );

            }

            @Override
            public void onRegionEntered(final Region region) {}

            @Override
            public void onRegionAbandoned(final Region region) {}


        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(!beaconManager.isBluetoothEnabled()) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
        } else if(beaconManager.isConnected()) {
            try {
                beaconManager.startRanging();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        beaconManager.stopMonitoring();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        beaconManager.disconnect();
        beaconManager = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                connect();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                getActionBar().setSubtitle("Bluetooth not enabled");
            }
            return;
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void connect() {
        try {
            beaconManager.connect(new OnServiceBoundListener() {
                @Override
                public void onServiceBound() {
                    try {
                        beaconManager.startMonitoring();
                        //beaconManager.startMonitoring(Region.EVERYWHERE);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I scanning for the beacons in the wrong function?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In `onStart()` you invoke `BeaconManager.startRanging()`. On the contrary, in `onStop()` you invoke `BeaconManager.stopMonitoring()`.

Well, this does not work that way. You can either range or monitor. You cannot perform both scans simultaneously. Mixing ranging and monitoring results in exception being raised.

While `ranging` you are focused on physical distance from remote devices that interest you.

Whereas, if you `monitor` them, you want to be rather notified of whether they are nearby or not. In other words, whether you are in specific region or not.

2. I see that you want to execute code once you find the beacon with specific minor value from `IMMEDIATE` distance. While what you wrote should work it is not preferrable way to solve it. You can enable filtering for specific values like minor via `Filters.newMajorFilter()`, or via `Filters.CustomFilter`

Have you seen the [kontakt-beacon-sample-admin-app](https://github.com/kontaktio/kontakt-beacon-admin-sample-app) ? This project demonstrates different approaches of kontakt.io's Android SDK usage.

Comment: Ty a lot for the help!! Can you explain me why it's not correct to perform the 2 methods simultaneously? 

I got the code working by using stopMonitoring() and startMonitoring() whenever I found a Beacon and ask the user if he wants to keep scanning (this way I found the beacon without any delay), do you think there's a cleaner solution?
Ty for the link. i'll check it out soon!

Comment: I've updated my answer. For more information, refer to http://docs.kontakt.io or https://github.com/kontaktio